# setScale(); not working in andriod studio 3.6.3

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, imageview, picasso

```
error: cannot find symbol
            matrix.setScale(scalee,scalee);
                  ^
  symbol:   method setScale(float,float)
  location: variable matrix of type Matrix
```

code:

```
private class ScaleListner extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            scalee = scalee * scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
            scalee = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scalee, 5f));
            matrix.setScale(scalee,scalee);
            noticeImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;

    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```